# In Amazon CloudSearch can you search a combination of relevance and recency using expressions?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I'm trying to balance my AWS CloudSearch search results between recency and relevance, and struggling to do (so not not *either* recency ***or*** relevance but a combination of the two).

I have a field, `pubdate`, which is a date field in the format 2001-12-25T00:00:00Z, in my index, and other text fields like `title`, `intro`, `main_body`, all of which contribute to the overall score.

I want a balance between showing the most recent results, and ones from the past which might be more relevant, but older.

At the moment I seem to be able to sort on `_score` *OR* `pubdate`, but not a combination of the two.

I've been trying to use expressions, e.g.

```
&expr.rank1=(0.2*pubdate)+(0.8*_score)&sort=rank1 desc
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect.

ref:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-expressions.html
[http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-dates.html](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-expressions.html)

Anyone any ideas or suggestions?